# Meta inserted through wp_insert_post gets messed up

Tags: php, urls, wp-insert-post

I'm extending the Woocommerce Product CSV Import functionality to import more data.

I'm inserting a CPT with 2 metadata, a string (URL) and a bool, and the post_meta inserted gets messed up. It inserts an array for the meta which should have the bool.

Snaptshot of code:

```
$link = array(
    'url'       => $url         // string
    'caption'   => $caption     // string
    'hide'      => $hide            // bol

$meta_input  = array(
    'ct_external_link_url'  => $link['url']
);

if( isset($link['hide']) ) {
    $meta_input += ['ct_hide_from_frontent' => $link['hide']];
}

$postarr = array(
    'post_title'    => $link['caption'],
    'post_type'     => 'ct_external_link',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_excerpt'  => $link['caption'],
    'meta_input'    => $meta_input
);

write_log("Args to insert external link post:");     // write_log ouputs to debug.txt
write_log($postarr);

$external_link_id = wp_insert_post($postarr);

$external_link = get_post($external_link_id, 'ARRAY_A');

if( !is_null($external_link)) {

    write_log("External link post:");
    write_log($external_link);

    write_log("External link post meta:");
    $meta = get_post_meta($external_link_id);
    write_log($meta);
}
```

Since I'm writing logs, these come out as following:

```
[15-Mar-2019 10:33:45 UTC] Args to insert external link post:
[15-Mar-2019 10:33:45 UTC] Array
(
    [post_title] => VÃ­deo 1
    [post_type] => ct_external_link
    [post_status] => publish
    [post_excerpt] => VÃ­deo 1
    [meta_input] => Array
        (
            [ct_external_link_url] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0IbjVq-fgs&ab_channel=CollegeMusic
            [ct_hide_from_frontent] => 1
        )

)
[15-Mar-2019 10:33:45 UTC] External link post meta:
[15-Mar-2019 10:33:45 UTC] Array
(
    [ct_hide_from_frontent] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
```

Note that, while the value for key 'ct_hide_from_frontent' is a bool in the meta_input, it comes out from the post_meta as an array. Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up just adding the meta after inserting the post, which doesn't give any error. It bypasses the problem without explaining it though...

```
$postarr = array(
    'post_title'    => $link['caption'],
    'post_type'     => 'ct_external_link',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_excerpt'  => $link['caption'],
);

$external_link_id = wp_insert_post($postarr);

if( !empty($external_link_id) ) {
    add_post_meta($external_link_id, 'ct_external_link_url', $doc['file'], true);

    if( isset($doc['hide']) ) {
        add_post_meta($external_link_id, 'ct_hide_from_frontent', $doc['hide']);
    }
}
```